# Connecting Java client to Marklogic 10 server is not working

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

We are migrating Marklogic 8 to Marklogic 10 and trying to connect the existing Java client application to Marklogic 10 but we are getting error .

> Root exception: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: ml-onecms.dev.tsg.hmhco.com:9004 failed to respond at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165) at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) at com.ixxus.hmh.service.http.connector.HttpClientExecutor.execute(HttpClientExecutor.java:114) at com.ixxus.hmh.jobs.CDMJobProcessor.doProcess(CDMJobProcessor.java:411) at com.ixxus.hmh.jobs.CDMJobProcessor.access$000(CDMJobProcessor.java:99) at com.ixxus.hmh.jobs.CDMJobProcessor$1.execute(CDMJobProcessor.java:194) at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464) at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:333) at com.ixxus.hmh.jobs.CDMJobProcessor.executeJob(CDMJobProcessor.java:209) at org.alfresco.schedule.ScheduledJobLockExecuter.execute(ScheduledJobLockExecuter.java:94) at org.alfresco.schedule.AbstractScheduledLockedJob.executeInternal(AbstractScheduledLockedJob.java:72) at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:114) at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216) at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)

Any idea what will be the issues?

Comment: And you have confirmed that you can connect to ml-onecms.dev.tsg.hmhco.com:9004 from that client machine, using a browser or curl? Hostname is resolving and hasn't changed from prior to the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's network related. Think firewall, DNS, connection timeout, things like that.

Beyond that, there's nothing we can tell from the stacktrace, it's something specific to your network.